# Parsing semi-structured text with native ansible templates/parser

Tags: templates, networking, ansible

I'm working on scraping information from CLI outputs on networking devices.  I've got the following block of text:

```
Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/1

  Name  : switch01
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5ff
  Link Status      : Up
  Port Enabled     : Yes
  Totals (Since boot or last clear) :
   Bytes Rx        : 202,420,676          Bytes Tx        : 857,343,705
   Unicast Rx      : 414,891              Unicast Tx      : 302,041
   Bcast/Mcast Rx  : 1,199,902            Bcast/Mcast Tx  : 6,511,408
  Errors (Since boot or last clear) :
   FCS Rx          : 0                    Drops Tx        : 0
   Alignment Rx    : 0                    Collisions Tx   : 0
   Runts Rx        : 0                    Late Colln Tx   : 0
   Giants Rx       : 0                    Excessive Colln : 0
   Total Rx Errors : 0                    Deferred Tx     : 0
  Others (Since boot or last clear) :
   Discard Rx      : 0                    Out Queue Len   : 0
   Unknown Protos  : 0
  Rates (5 minute weighted average) :
   Total Rx (bps) : 176                   Total Tx (bps) : 2,424
   Unicast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              Unicast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 0
   B/Mcast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              B/Mcast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 5
   Utilization Rx  :     0 %              Utilization Tx  :     0 %


 Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/2

  Name  : switch02
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5fe
  Link Status      : Up
  Port Enabled     : Yes
  Totals (Since boot or last clear) :
   Bytes Rx        : 160,277,797          Bytes Tx        : 3,084,489,191
   Unicast Rx      : 1,765,286            Unicast Tx      : 1,700,199
   Bcast/Mcast Rx  : 32,913               Bcast/Mcast Tx  : 6,546,225
  Errors (Since boot or last clear) :
   FCS Rx          : 0                    Drops Tx        : 0
   Alignment Rx    : 0                    Collisions Tx   : 0
   Runts Rx        : 0                    Late Colln Tx   : 0
   Giants Rx       : 0                    Excessive Colln : 0
   Total Rx Errors : 0                    Deferred Tx     : 0
  Others (Since boot or last clear) :
   Discard Rx      : 0                    Out Queue Len   : 0
   Unknown Protos  : 0
  Rates (5 minute weighted average) :
   Total Rx (bps) : 0                     Total Tx (bps) : 2,416
   Unicast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              Unicast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 0
   B/Mcast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              B/Mcast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 5
   Utilization Rx  :     0 %              Utilization Tx  :     0 %
```

I'm using the following template:

```
    ---
    - example: "Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/A4"
      getval: '^\sStatus\sand\sCounters\s\-\sPort\sCounters\sfor\sport\s(?P<port_number>\d\/(\w\d+|\d+))'
      result:
        "{{ port_number }}":
          local_port: "{{ port_number }}"
      shared: true
    
    - example: "  Link Status      : Up"
      getval: '^\s\sLink\sStatus\s+\:\s(?P<port_status>[^\s]+)'
      result:
        "{{ port_number }}":
          port_status: "{{ port_status }}"
```

I keep getting an error:

"Native parser returned an error while parsing. Error: 'port_number' is undefined"

The port_number variable is being collected properly.  If I comment out the 2nd task in the template, I successfully am pulling the port number out and I've verified it's getting defined.  I only get the error when I reference the port_number variable again in a subsequent task.

I've got other templates that use the same "shared: true" mechanism for sharing the variable across the template, but for some reason this one isn't working.  Any thoughts?

I've changed variable names and verified my capture regex is working.

Comment: Make sure the switch doesn't provide YAML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There is no space in front of *Status*. Fix the regex:

```yaml
  getval: '^\sStatus\sand\sCounters ... '
```

Correct:

```yaml
  getval: '^Status\sand\sCounters ... '
```

---

Details: The indentation of the *'Status ...'* lines is not consistent. The second *Status* line is shifted 1 space to the right. This explains the first *getval* not matching the first *Status* line. As a consequence, *port_number* is undefined when the second *getval* matches the first *'Link Status ...'*

```yaml
Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/1

  Name  : switch01
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5ff
  Link Status      : Up
  ...

 Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/2

  Name  : switch02
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5fe
  Link Status      : Up
  ...
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    stdout: "{{ lookup('file', 'stdout.txt') }}"

  tasks:

    - ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        text: "{{ stdout }}"
        parser:
          name: ansible.netcommon.native
          template_path: templates/property.yml
        set_fact: property

    - debug:
        var: property
```

Fixed *getval*

```yaml
shell> cat templates/property.yml
- example: "Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/A4"
  getval: '^Status\sand\sCounters\s\-\sPort\sCounters\sfor\sport\s(?P<port_number>\d\/(\w\d+|\d+))'
  result:
    "{{ port_number }}":
      local_port: "{{ port_number }}"
  shared: true
    
- example: "  Link Status      : Up"
  getval: '^\s\sLink\sStatus\s+\:\s(?P<port_status>[^\s]+)'
  result:
    "{{ port_number }}":
      port_status: "{{ port_status }}"
```

Fixed indentation

```yaml
shell> cat stdout.txt
Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/1

  Name  : switch01
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5ff
  Link Status      : Up
  Port Enabled     : Yes
  Totals (Since boot or last clear) :
   Bytes Rx        : 202,420,676          Bytes Tx        : 857,343,705
   Unicast Rx      : 414,891              Unicast Tx      : 302,041
   Bcast/Mcast Rx  : 1,199,902            Bcast/Mcast Tx  : 6,511,408
  Errors (Since boot or last clear) :
   FCS Rx          : 0                    Drops Tx        : 0
   Alignment Rx    : 0                    Collisions Tx   : 0
   Runts Rx        : 0                    Late Colln Tx   : 0
   Giants Rx       : 0                    Excessive Colln : 0
   Total Rx Errors : 0                    Deferred Tx     : 0
  Others (Since boot or last clear) :
   Discard Rx      : 0                    Out Queue Len   : 0
   Unknown Protos  : 0
  Rates (5 minute weighted average) :
   Total Rx (bps) : 176                   Total Tx (bps) : 2,424
   Unicast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              Unicast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 0
   B/Mcast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              B/Mcast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 5
   Utilization Rx  :     0 %              Utilization Tx  :     0 %


Status and Counters - Port Counters for port 1/2

  Name  : switch02
  MAC Address      : 089734-02b5fe
  Link Status      : Up
  Port Enabled     : Yes
  Totals (Since boot or last clear) :
   Bytes Rx        : 160,277,797          Bytes Tx        : 3,084,489,191
   Unicast Rx      : 1,765,286            Unicast Tx      : 1,700,199
   Bcast/Mcast Rx  : 32,913               Bcast/Mcast Tx  : 6,546,225
  Errors (Since boot or last clear) :
   FCS Rx          : 0                    Drops Tx        : 0
   Alignment Rx    : 0                    Collisions Tx   : 0
   Runts Rx        : 0                    Late Colln Tx   : 0
   Giants Rx       : 0                    Excessive Colln : 0
   Total Rx Errors : 0                    Deferred Tx     : 0
  Others (Since boot or last clear) :
   Discard Rx      : 0                    Out Queue Len   : 0
   Unknown Protos  : 0
  Rates (5 minute weighted average) :
   Total Rx (bps) : 0                     Total Tx (bps) : 2,416
   Unicast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              Unicast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 0
   B/Mcast Rx (Pkts/sec) : 0              B/Mcast Tx (Pkts/sec) : 5
   Utilization Rx  :     0 %              Utilization Tx  :     0 %
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  property:
    1/1:
      local_port: 1/1
      port_status: Up
    1/2:
      local_port: 1/2
      port_status: Up
```

Comment: Indeed, good catch. Now it is working in my environment too and as it should according the module examples. This answer here should become definitely the accepted one ...